Ontology and controlled vocabulary how to model
I need help with modelling this situation
I have two parts to my business say marketing and industrial and each of this flows have set of actions like action 1 action 2 action 3 action 4 , so I was thinking to add the actions as controlled vocabulary so we can use only these actions while creating instances and not as subclasses but now some of these actions are part of both the flows then how should we model this should we then at instance level add action hasType Marketing or there is any way to have this in the ontology itself

Please provide a minimal complete ontology illustrating the problem you are experiencing.
